# _make_key function in Python's LRU cache code

Tags: python, lru

I am looking into Python's **Least Recently Used (LRU) cache** implementation [here](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/578078-py26-and-py30-backport-of-python-33s-lru-cache/).

Can someone please explain what the `_make_key` function is doing?

```
def _make_key(args, kwds, typed,
             kwd_mark = (object(),),
             fasttypes = {int, str, frozenset, type(None)},
             sorted=sorted, tuple=tuple, type=type, len=len):
    'Make a cache key from optionally typed positional and keyword arguments'
    key = args
    if kwds:
        sorted_items = sorted(kwds.items())
        key += kwd_mark
        for item in sorted_items:
            key += item
    if typed:
        key += tuple(type(v) for v in args)
        if kwds:
            key += tuple(type(v) for k, v in sorted_items)
    elif len(key) == 1 and type(key[0]) in fasttypes:
        return key[0]
    return _HashedSeq(key)
```

Comment: Like.... the whole function? Can you narrow down your question? Is there a specific line you don't understand?

Comment: Kind of whole function. What is the role of `sort` here? what is `kwd_mark` ?

Answer (score 2):

### Summary

The *_make_key()* function flattens the arguments into a compact tuple that can be used to determine whether the arguments for two calls are the same.

### Generated keys

The call `f(10, 20, x=30, y=40)` and `f(10, 20, y=40, x=30)` both have the same key:

```
(10, 20, <object object at 0x7fae2bb25040>, 'x', 30, 'y', 40)
```

The *10* and *20* positional arguments are record in the order specified.

The *kwd_mark* separates the keyword arguments from the positional arguments.

The keyword arguments are sorted so that `x=30, y=40` is recognized as being the same as `y=40, x=30`.

If *typed* is true, then the key also records the argument types:

```
(10, 20,                            # positional args
<object object at 0x7fae2bb25040>,  # kwd_mark
'x', 30, 'y', 40,                   # keyword args
<class 'int'>, <class 'int'>,       # types of the args  
<class 'int'>, <class 'int'>)
```

Answer (score 1):

The function is converting a set of function arguments to a sequence that (a) can be hashed and (b) returns the same hash value for the same arguments, if a function is invoked multiple times with the same arguments.

Obviously, `args` and `kwargs` are intended to be the positional and keyword arguments of a generic function definition:

```
def foo(*args, **kwargs):
    pass
```

`args` is a list, which is hashable as long as all its elements are hashable; `kwargs` is however a `dict` which is not a hashable type. So the function uses `.items()` to convert it to a list of key-value pairs; it is then sorted because the hash value of a list is sensitive to the order of elements, and a `dict` can list its items in arbitrary order.

The purpose of `kwd_mark` is to ensure that keyword arguments cannot be confused with positional arguments that might happen to consist of the same key-value pair as an item of `kwargs`. As a default argument, its value is assigned when the function is defined; this guarantees that its sentinel object will never appear as a function argument.